# Spring data rest: Adding JPA Criteria API queries in Spring Data Rest entity repository

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I want to add JPA criteria api queries in repository which I have defined in my spring data rest demo. And then expose those queries using GET. Till now, I have not discovered, how to do the same. If anyone has done the same, any light on the same/ Sample code shall be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you [followed the conventions for custom methods](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/1.7.2.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-implementations) all the custom methods are exposed as

> [BASE_URI]/search/[CUSTOM_METHODS]

. Also there are little more constraints on these custom methods to exposed like all parameters to custom methods must be annotated with `@Param`. Optionally custom methods could return `Page<?>`, `List<?>` object and also can accept `Pageable` and `Sort` type params.